# Euclidean Distance in Tensorflow, convert matrix

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a knn classification project, which needs to calculate euclidean distance with tensorflow for comparison.

The original code without tensorflow is like this:

```js
def euclidean_distance(self,x1, x2):
        distance = 0.0
        for i in range(len(x1)):
            distance += pow( x1[i] - x2[i], 2)
        print(distance)
        return math.sqrt(distance)
```

and with tensorflow is like this:

```html
distance = 0.0
        for i in range(len(x1)):
            distance = tf.negative(tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(x1, x2)))))
        return distance
```

Is this right? Because of that code distance became tensor, and I need a method for converting that tensor into a normal matrix.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get nd array(matrix) you need to run the graph like blow

```
session=tf.Session()
nd_distance=session.run(distance)
```

You have to change your code to

```
......
......
     distance = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(x1, x2))))
     nd_distance=session.run(distance)
     print (nd_distance)
     return nd_distance
```

I don't see the need for `tf.negative` function and `for loop`

Comment: when im trying to print distance it was like

Tensor("Sqrt_2457:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Sqrt_2458:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

but nothing happened if im trying to print nd_distance like your code, any suggestion ?

Comment: what are the value of x1 and x2? are they tensors too?

Comment: nope, it is matrix, like this 
https://s1.postimg.org/o2x1vdypr/postimage.png

it is feature vector matrix, after tf-idf

Comment: I can't figure out from this code, can u post the whole code?

Comment: its too long and kinda private, thanks for helping anyways, i appreciate it :D

Comment: @Elucist may be you forgot to call print function. please check if you added print ( nd_distance) before the return statement.